# Find first matching regex from list of regexes

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a list of regexes like such (this is a simple example, the real code has more complex regexes):

```
regs = [r'apple', 'strawberry', r'pear', r'.*berry', r'fruit: [a-z]*']
```

I want to **exactly** match one of the regexes above (so `^regex$`) and return the index. Additionally, I want to match the leftmost regex. So `find('strawberry')` should return 1 while `find('blueberry')` should return 3. I'm going to re-use the same set of regexes a lot, so precomputation is fine.

This is what I've coded, but it feels bad. The regex should be able to know which one got matched, and I feel this is terribly inefficient (keep in mind that the example above is simplified, and the real regexes are more complicated and in larger numbers):

```
import re

regs_compiled = [re.compile(reg) for reg in regs]
regs_combined = re.compile('^' +
                           '|'.join('(?:{})'.format(reg) for reg in regs) +
                           '$')

def find(s):
    if re.match(regs_combined, s):
        for i, reg in enumerate(regs_compiled):
            if re.match(reg, s):
                return i

    return -1
```

Is there a way to find out which subexpression(s) were used to match the regex without looping explicitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to figure out which subexpression of the regular expression matched the string would be to use capturing groups for every one and then check which group is not `None`. But this would require that no subexpression uses capturing groups on its own.

E.g.

```
>>> regs_combined = re.compile('^' +
                           '|'.join('({})'.format(reg) for reg in regs) +
                           '$')
>>> m = re.match(regs_combined, 'strawberry')
>>> m.groups()
(None, 'strawberry', None, None, None)
>>> m.lastindex - 1
1
```

Other than that, the standard regular expression implementation does not provide further information. You could of course build your own engine that exposes that information, but apart from your very special use case, it’s difficult to make this practically work in other situations—which is probably why this is not provided by existing solutions.

Comment: Since I'm only matching and don't care about extracting groups, would it be possible to transform the regexes I'm matching into non-capturing groups before combining them?

Comment: No, because as I wrote that’s the only way to actually get any information from it.

Comment: If you want to avoid storing the full match in the match object, you could use `'(?:(){})'` as the format string instead. This will use non-capturing groups but put an empty capturing group (just for identification purposes) at the start. Then you look for the group with the content `''` and you have your index.

Comment: There's no need to do `enumerate(m.groups())`: just get `m.lastindex`

Comment: @PM2Ring Cool, didn’t know that! Thanks :)

Comment: I'd forgotten that it existed myself. I just re-discovered it while I was working on my own answer. :)

Comment: It *seems* to work when I use non-capturing groups inside the inner regexes. E.g. `regs = [r'apple', 'strawberry', r'pear', r'(?:berry)*', r'fruit: [a-z]*']` to match "berryberryberry". Are you _sure_ it doesn't work? If yes, could you explain it further?

Comment: @orlp: Sure, you can use non-capturing groups inside the inner regexes, but you need to use capturing groups in the outer regexes so you can get their indices. Conversely, you _can't_ use capturing groups inside the inner regexes or it'll screw up the indexing.

Comment: Oh, I get now what you were asking. Yes, you could convert capturing groups in the original subexpressions into non-capturing groups before combining them to make this work properly. But then you need a way to safely identify capturing groups inside regular expressions, which itself probably isn’t so easy to do.